# Interpretation and understanding of the relation involving conditional probabilities and conditional densities.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, density-function, bayes-theorem

In the context of an astrophysics survey , I need to understand the relation I have to use for photometric bins. I transfer the original post on math.stackexchange.com since the issue is more about a mathematical problem than a physics problematic, so I think that someone will be able to explain the interpretation and the subtilities of the equations below. Then, I could get a mathematical point of view of these relations.

Considering $p_{ph}(z_p|z)$ the  probability to  measure a photometric redshift equal to $z_p$ knowing the real redshift is $z$ and given $n(z)$ the density distribution of objects, I have the following formula which gives the density $n_i$ of galaxies into $i$-th bin and that I would like to understand :

$$
n_{i}(z)=\frac{\int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}} \mathrm{d} z_{\mathrm{p}}\,n(z)\,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}} | z)}{\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} \int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,\mathrm{d} z \,\mathrm{d} z_{\mathrm{p}} \,n(z) \,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}} | z)}
\quad(1)$$

with $\left(z_{i}^{-}, z_{i}^{+}\right)$ which are the values of both sides (+ and -) of redshift $i$ bin.

**Here my attempt to simplify :** with Bayes theorem, one has :

$$p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}} | z) = p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z|z_{\mathrm{p}})\,\dfrac{p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}})}{p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z)}\quad(2)$$

and Moreover, the bottom term of $(1)$ gives :

$$\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} \int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,\mathrm{d} z \,\mathrm{d} z_{\mathrm{p}} \,n(z) \,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}} | z)$$

$$=\int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,n(z)\,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}})\,\text{d}z_{\mathrm{p}}\quad(3)$$

So, by combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get :

$$
n_{i}(z)=\dfrac{n(z)\,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}})}{\int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,n(z)\,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}})\,\text{d}z_{\mathrm{p}}}\quad(4)$$

**BUT from this $(4)$ I don't know how conclude about the interpretation of this objects density into the redshift of bin $i$.**

Surely there is an error in my attempt to simplify the expression $(1$) but I don't where.

**If someone could help me to grasp better the subitilities of the relation $(1)$, from a mathematical or physics point of views, this would be nice to explain it.**

**UPDATE 1:**

> In particular, I don't agree with Equations (3) and (4). Indeed, using
> Bayes theorem in the bottom term of Equation (1) leads to
>
> $$ \int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} \int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+} dz dz_p n(z) p_{ph}(z|z_p)\frac{p_{ph}(z_p)}{p_{ph}(z)} $$
>
> But $p_{ph}(z | z_p) dz$ is not equal to $p_{ph}(z)$, so you can't
> simplify the fraction out, like you do in Equation (3)
>
> In addition, $dz_p n(z) p_{ph} (z_p | z)$ has no reason to be
> constant, so you can't easily remove the integration sign, like you do
> in Equation (4).

For equation $(3)$, I wanted to simplify by :

$$\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} \int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,\mathrm{d} z \,\mathrm{d} z_{\mathrm{p}} \,n(z) \,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}} | z)= \int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,n(z)\,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}})\,\text{d}z_{\mathrm{p}}\quad(5)$$

since we should have : $$p_{ph}(z) = \int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} p_{ph}(z | z_p)\,dz_p\quad(6)$$, shouldn't we ?

In comment above, you talk about the relation : $dz_p\,p_{ph} (z_p | z)$, not the equation $(6)$ above, do you agree ?

From an intuitive point of view, I agree that ratio between density $n_i(z)$ and total density $n(z)$ is equal to the ratio between the probability of getting objects of redshift $z_p$ knowing the true redshift
$z$ by integrating over $z_p$ and the  total density integrated over $z_p$ and $z$.

But as soon as we have to formulate it with mathematics and conditional probabilities, it's more difficult.

Maybe I shoud consider for example the following relation which is the equivalent of Bayes theorem but with density functions (called conditional density) :

$$g\left(x | y_{0}\right)=\frac{f\left(x, y_{0}\right)}{\int f\left(t, y_{0}\right) \mathrm{d} t}\quad(7)$$

But I don't know how to connect this equation $(7)$ with equation $(1)$.

Sorry if I misunderstood : your comment will be precious, that's why I want to clarify this step.

**UPDATE 2 :**

**1)**

> The numerator of Equation (1) $$ \int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+} dz_p n(z) p_{ph}(z_p | z) $$ is simply the number of of samples in the $i^{th}$
> photometric bin. Indeed, at a given redshift $[z, z+dz]$, there are
> $n(z).dz$ samples. Each of these samples has a probability $p_{ph}(z_p| z)$ of ending up in the $i^{th}$ bin. So by integrating over
> $[z_i^-, z_i^+]$, you get the number of samples with true redshift $z$
> and a photometric redshift in that bin.

The problem is that, in the numerator of equation $(1)$ :

$$\int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+} dz_p n(z) p_{ph}\,(z_p | z)$$

**we integrate over $z_p$ and not $z$, so we can't consider the number of samples $n(z)\,\text{d}z$ and after say that we compute the probability to be in $i-th$ bin to have $n_i(z)$ samples/density value. Indeed, $\text{dz}$ doesn't appear in the numerator of equation $(1)$.**

Do you agree with this issue for me ?

**2)** I would like to make the connection between what I have put into my **UPDATE 1**, i.e the conditional density or maybe I should rather express the condditional probability like this :

$$g\left(x | y_{0}\right)=\dfrac{f\left(x, y_{0}\right)}{\int f\left(t, y_{0}\right) \mathrm{d} t}\quad(8)$$

This relation is qualified of "Bayes theorem" for continuous case :

But If I inegrate this expression $(8)$, I get :

$$\int\,g\left(x | y_{0}\right)\,\text{d}y_0=\int\,\dfrac{f\left(x, y_{0}\right)\,\text{d}y_0}{\int f\left(t, y_{0}\right) \mathrm{d} t}\quad\neq\quad P(X|y_0)\quad(9)$$

How to make appear the term $P(X|y_0)$ from equation $(8)$ ?

To visualize the result expected, you can see below each color corresponding to the i-th redshift considered and computed from the eq(1). I hope this will help.

[[image: Plot of <span class=]$n_i(z)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9jqx.png)

Any help/remark/suggeston is welcome

Comment: Your integral notation is a bit confusing. If I understand correctly, by

$$
\int_{z_{\mathrm{min}}}^{z_{\mathrm{max}}}\int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dz_{\mathrm p} \ldots
$$

in the denominator of $(1)$ you mean what would more conventionally be written either as

$$
\int_{z_{\mathrm{min}}}^{z_{\mathrm{max}}}\,\mathrm dz\int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+}\,\mathrm dz_{\mathrm p} \ldots
$$

or as

$$
\int_{z_{\mathrm{min}}}^{z_{\mathrm{max}}}\int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+}\ldots\mathrm dz_{\mathrm p}\,\mathrm dz\;?
$$

Comment: In fact, perhaps this is part of the problem? In $(3)$ you seem to have confused yourself with this notation. On the left-hand side of $(3)$, $z$ is an integration variable, whereas on the right-hand side it has turned into a free variable?

Comment: @joriki Thanks for your quick answer. I think the right notation is : $$\int_{z_{\mathrm{min}}}^{z_{\mathrm{max}}}\,\mathrm dz\int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+}\,\mathrm dz_{\mathrm p} \ldots$$ but there is also the factor $n(z)$ included in the integration regards to $$\text{d}z . What do you think about ?

Comment: That may be a misunderstanding. My problem was not with $n(z)$ appearing in the integral. The problem I was trying to point out is that $z$ appears as an integration variable (that is, a bound dummy variable that does not exist outside the scope of the integral) on the left-hand side of $(3)$ whereas it appears as a free variable on the right-hand side of $(3)$. This makes $(3)$ meaningless in a very fundamental logical sense that has nothing to do with the details of the calculation.

Comment: @joriki . Thanks for your answer. Actually, I wonder if I can interpret $$\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} \int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,\mathrm{d} z \,\mathrm{d} z_{\mathrm{p}} \,n(z) \,p_{\mathrm{ph}}(z_{\mathrm{p}} | z)$$  like a clasical double integral : $$\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}} \int_{z_{i}^{-}}^{z_{i}^{+}}\,n(y) \,f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x$$ with $$p_{ph}\,(z_p | z) \sim f(x,y)$$ : what do you think about it ?

Comment: Well, that would be the other interpretation, no? I asked above which of the two you meant, and you responded that you meant the one where $z_{\min}$ and $z_{\max}$ are the limits for $z$; now you're proposing the other one, where $z_{\min}$ and $z_{\max}$ are the limits for $x$, i.e. $z_{\mathrm p}$. I can't tell you which of these two you mean; you need to tell me. In either case, what you call a "classical double integral" doesn't yield an expression in which one of its integration variables appears as a free variable.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding : in my last comment (that I think it's right), I make the correspondance : $$x\sim z_p$$ and $$y\sim z$$ . So I integrate $x$ (i.e $z_p$) over $\int_{z_i^-}^{z_i^+}$ and $y$ over $\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}}$. That's why I wondered if I could consider equation $(3)$ like a "classical double integral", i.e by making the correspondance $$p_{ph}\,(z_p | z) \sim f(x,y)$$. Am I in the right interpretation ? Regards